# How do you impose a case insensitive unique constraint on a Firebird field value?

Tags: sql, constraints, firebird, unique-constraint

I want to add a field called email to table AGENT. I want the values of AGENT.email to be unique across the table and I want this uniqueness to be case insensitive.

For example adding "MARY@USA.COM" would violate the constraint if "mary@usa.com" already exists in the table. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a unique index on `lower` of email column on the table like so:

```
create unique index email_unq_idx on agent computed by (lower(email));
```

Comment: I'm running Firebird 2.1

Comment: @Jonathan Cheers mate :)

Comment: You could also use a case insensitive collation for the column; I'll post a full answer later.

Comment: And collation way would be better - that would allow the index to be used for SELECTs too. Expression index would almost only work for uniqueness check

Answer (score 4):

To impose a case insensitive constraint, the best way is to create the column with a case insensitive collation like `unicode_ci_ai` - this collation is also accent insensitive, which you may or may not want -, and add a unique constraint (or unique index) on that column:

```
create table addressbook
(
    id integer not null,
    emailaddress varchar(150) character set utf8 collate unicode_ci_ai,
    constraint pk_addressbook primary key (id),
    constraint uc_emailaddress unique (emailaddress)
);
```

or to add the field to an existing table:

```
alter table addressbook
    add emailaddress2 varchar(150) character set utf8 
            constraint uc_emailaddress2 unique collate unicode_ci_ai
```

Alternative collations would be `unicode_ci` (only case insensitive) or other [built-in case insensitive collations](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-appx06-charsets) depending on the character set used, or to [create your own specific collation](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-ddl-collation-create).

The advantage of this solution over the one presented by Gurwinder is that it also allows you to select case (and accent) insensitively without having to use `lower` in your where clause.